# PHP Image insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, upload, insert, blob

G'day, I'm trying to upload an image to a table in my database called "store", but it doesn't seem to be working. No errors are being displayed but the error message I have uploaded appears, so there's no problem with the syntax.

Here's the two interlinking PHP files I've written:

index.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 File:
<input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" value="Upload">
     </form>

    <?php
     // connect to database
    include "connect.inc.php";

     //file properties
     $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

     if(!isset($file))
echo "Please select an image.";
     else
      {
      $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
      $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
      $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

      if($image_size==FALSE)
   echo "That's not an image.";
    else
    {
if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES  ('','$image_name','$image')")) 
    echo "Problem uploading image.";        
else
{
 $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
 echo "Image uploaded.<p />Your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
}
    }
   }    
   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

get.php

```
       <?php
include "connect.inc.php";

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: Can you also put how your database is set up (table `description`)?  Also, `mysql_` functions are no longer supported, consider using `mysqli_` or PDO. ^^ (reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: This is just for a personal project, I'm not publishing this.

Comment: So, that a 'no' for the table's `description` then?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with reading the contents of the file and transfer back. It looks like the content of file is not placed in a database field. Check lenght of this field, the content can be very long (mediumtext or longtext).

Also you need to check the type of uploading file, you can do it by function "mime_content_type". And if user will upload gif. or .png file header("Content-type: image/jpeg") would set wrong information, you can use more versatile header header("Content-type: image/*").
And use for the live sites PDO or other ORM, because your method have many vulnerabilities.